# Tensor to PIL Image

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I am using the [super-image](https://github.com/eugenesiow/super-image) library to upscale an image. Here is the `ImageLoader` class from `super-image`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

import torch
from torch import Tensor


class ImageLoader:
    @staticmethod
    def load_image(image: Image):
        lr = np.array(image.convert('RGB'))
        lr = lr[::].astype(np.float32).transpose([2, 0, 1]) / 255.0
        return torch.as_tensor([lr])

    @staticmethod
    def _process_image_to_save(pred: Tensor):
        pred = pred.data.cpu().numpy()
        pred = pred[0].transpose((1, 2, 0)) * 255.0
        # pred = pred[scale:-scale, scale:-scale, :]
        pred = cv2.cvtColor(pred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        return pred

    @staticmethod
    def save_image(pred: Tensor, output_file: str):
        pred = ImageLoader._process_image_to_save(pred)
        cv2.imwrite(output_file, pred)
        

    # -- snip --
```

Currently only a `save_image` convenience method has been provided although I wish to convert the array directly into a PIL `Image`.
I am struggling to find how the image data is stored in order to correctly convert to the PIL `Image`.

Here is what I have tried so far but it only gives an incorrect output image.

```
def upscale(image, scale):
    inputs = ImageLoader.load_image(image)
    model = PanModel.from_pretrained("pan", scale=scale)
    preds = model(inputs)

    pred = ImageLoader._process_image_to_save(preds)
    image = Image.fromarray(pred, "RGB")
    image.show()

image = Image.open("temp.png")
upscale(image, 4)
```

Here is an example of the image that is shown when trying to use `fromarray()`

[image]

Comment: file a bug with the author of the library.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It's not a bug. I just am trying to work out how to manipulate the data into the correct format.

Comment: clearly there is data corruption. you should track that down first.

Comment: Add `print(pred.dtype, pred.shape, pred.max(), pred.min())` immediately after it is created and share the output.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if i am not mistaken u just wanted to use the image as a pil instead of loading it directly correct?

```py
import numpy as np
import requests
import torch
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from super_image import EdsrModel, ImageLoader, PanModel

# This function is what you need
def postproc(pred: torch.Tensor) -> Image.Image:
  pred = pred.data.cpu().numpy()
  pred = pred[0].transpose((1, 2, 0)) * 255.0
  
  pred = pred.astype(np.uint8)
  return Image.fromarray(pred)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  url = 'https://paperswithcode.com/media/datasets/Set5-0000002728-07a9793f_zA3bDjj.jpg'
  image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

  model = EdsrModel.from_pretrained('eugenesiow/edsr-base', scale=2)
  # model = PanModel.from_pretrained("eugenesiow/pan", scale=2)
  inputs = ImageLoader.load_image(image)
  preds = model(inputs)

  upscaled_img = postproc(preds)
  plt.imshow(upscaled_img)
```